# sendgrid php api not sending emails when 'addContent' used in if block

Tags: php, email, html-email, sendgrid

Im working on an application where I've created a user registration system. So when a user registers an email is sent to the account, Im using an email class to send email. Before using sendgrid I was using phpmailer and it was working perfectly fine in this format, but it doesn't works with sendgrid.
So when i use this code without if and else for '$type', it works completely fine, but does not works with if else and the page loading never ends!

Some help would be appreciated!!
This is the code

```
<?php

class email {
   public function sendEmail($name, $email, $url, $type, $subject){
    require '../../vendor/autoload.php'; // If you're using Composer (recommended)
    $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
    $email->setFrom("mymail@gmail.com", "Example User");
    $email->setSubject($subject);
    $email->addTo($email, $name);
    if($type === "CONFIRM"){
      $email->addContent(
        'text/html', 'CONFIRM MESSAGE'
    );

    } else if($type === "FORGOT"){
      $email->addContent(
        'text/html', 'FORGOT MESSAGE'
      );

    }
    $apiKey = 'api_key';
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
    try {
        $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
        print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
        print_r($response->headers());
        print $response->body() . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }




   }

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you try to use 'text/plain' in place of 'text/html'. Also are you sure $type has values of FORGOT or CONFIRM ?

Comment: Still doesn't work, yes the type values are confirm and forgot. Any other idea why this isn't happening

Comment: 1) So if you remove the if..else and have just one line eg. $email->addContent('text/html', 'CONFIRM MESSAGE'); does it work then? 
2) Try == in place to ===